# TreeView не обновляется после добавления нового node WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Я новенькая в программировании, поэтому не судите строго :-)
я хочу добавить возможность добавлять в `TreeView` новые `nodes` по запросу юзера с помощью right click на мышь
В данный момент я научилась добавлять один `node`, который появляется в UI, но при добавлении других, UI не обновляется и `nodes` остаются только в `IList<TreeItemViewModel> items`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

последующие `nodes` не добавляются в папку `xxxxxxxxxxx`

`XAML`

```
<TreeView Name="PackageTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Value.RootNodes}" MouseDoubleClick="PackageTreeView_MouseDoubleClick" >
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle >
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TreeItemContextMenu}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                    <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="TreeViewSelectedItemChanged" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeView.Resources >
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                    DataType="{x:Type viewModel:TreeItemViewModel}" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MouseRightButtonDown="UIElement_OnMouseRightButtonDown">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}" />
                        <TextBlock ToolTip="{Binding CountImages}"
                            Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>

        </TreeView>
```

Code

```
public void AddNode(ITreeNode node)
        {
            IList<TreeItemViewModel> items = new List<TreeItemViewModel>();
            for (int idx = 0; idx < 1; idx++)
            {
                TreeItemViewModel item = new TreeItemViewModel(node, this);
                
                items.Add(item);
            }
            Children.AddRange(items);
            IsExpanded = !IsExpanded;
            IsExpanded = true;
        }


public bool IsExpanded
        {
            get => _isExpanded;
            set
            {
                if (value != _isExpanded)
                {
                    _isExpanded = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }

                // Expand all the way up to the root.
                if (_isExpanded && Parent != null)
                {
                    Parent.IsExpanded = true;
                }

                // Lazy load the child items, if necessary.
                if (HasDummyChild)
                {
                    Children.Remove(DummyChild);
                    LoadChildren();
                }
            }
        }
 private void LoadChildren()
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
            Children.AddRange((from child in _treeNode.Children select new TreeItemViewModel(child, this)));
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     Returns true if this object's Children have not yet been populated.
        /// </summary>
        public bool HasDummyChild => Children.Count == 1 && Children[0] == DummyChild;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приведу общий пример. Здесь 2 нюанса:

- Свойство, обновление которого ожидается в интерфейсе, должно вызывать событие `PropertyChanged`, а класс, в котором оно находится, реализовывать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
- Коллекция, обновление которой ожидается в интерфейсе должна реализовывать интрефейс `INotifyCollectionChanged`, и такая коллекция существует - `ObservableCollection`.

#### Привязка дерева с автоматическим обновлением интерфейса

Реализуем интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`

```cs
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Реализуем ноду

```cs
public class TreeNode : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<TreeNode> _children = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>();
    private string _name;

    public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Children
    {
        get => _children;
        set
        {
            _children = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Реализуем свойство с корневыми нодами

```cs
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<TreeNode> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Items
    {
        get => _items;
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>
        {
            new TreeNode{ Name = "Root" }
        };
    }
}
```

Привяжем `TreeView` к этим данным

```xml
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

На этом этапе `TreeView` полностью динамически связан с данными - любые изменения в данных повлекут за собой немедленные изменения в интерфейсе. То есть можно пересоздавать/заменять или менять местами коллекции, можно то же самое вытворять с элементами этих коллекций, в любых количествах в любое время. *(Главное помнить, что изменения в данных, к которым привязан интерфейс, следует делать в UI потоке, в противном случае `ObservableCollection` вполне оправданно выдаст вам исключение `NotSupportedException`, или еще что-нибудь поломается)*.

#### Контекстное меню "Добавить элемент"

Потребуются команды (вместо мучений с обработчиками событий).

И есть вот такой класс для удобного использования команд.

```cs
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
        => (_execute, _canExecute) = (execute, canExecute);

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);

    public void Execute(object parameter)
        => _execute(parameter);
}
```

Далее реализуем добавление дочернего элемента в команде ноды, немного доработав класс `TreeNode`

```cs
public class TreeNode : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<TreeNode> _children = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>();
    private string _name;
    private ICommand _addChildCommand;

    public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Children
    {
        get => _children;
        set
        {
            _children = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddChildCommand => _addChildCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        Children.Add(new TreeNode { Name = Name + "-Child" + (Children.Count + 1) });
    });
}
```

И добавим контекстное меню в разметку

```xml
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Add child" Command="{Binding AddChildCommand}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Для удаления элемента потребуется ссылка на родительскую коллекцию, как у вас уже реализовано в коде из вопроса. Выглядеть это может так.

```xml
<MenuItem Header="Remove" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}"/>
```

```cs
public ICommand RemoveCommand => _removeCommand ??= new RelayCommand(parameter =>
{
    ParentItems.Remove(this);
});
```

---

Если вам принципиально реагировать на правую кнопку мыши вместо контекстного меню, можно привязаться к команде например вот так. У вас в разметке `StackPanel`, покажу на ее примере.

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding MouseAction="RightClick" Command="{Binding AddChildCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel.InputBindings>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

*При реализации этого задания ни одного обработчика событий не пострадало.*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]