# Реализация переключения названий месяцев по стрелкам (не в календаре)

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

Создаю приложение на WPF и есть необходимость в том, чтобы через стрелочки просто переключались месяца.

[image]

Стрелки это просто `Button`, название месяца выводится в `TextBlock`. Пробовала через `AddMonths`, но возникает проблема с получение месяца текущего в `TextBlock`, чтобы от него отталкиваться в ту или иную сторону. Перевод из string в `DateTime` не помог, так как не понимает текст месяца соответственно. Прошу помочь любым рабочим вариантом, уже нет идей как это можно сделать...

Comment: Есть у меня один минипроект как пример ([скачать](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/9lyXdiywiAg-nQ)), просто сделано визуальное преобразование даты в JS милисекунды и обратно. Там есть кнопки переключения по дням, вправо-влево. Кнопки переключения по месяцам можно сделать точно так же. Если найду время, попробую написать ответ, но пока не могу.

Comment: `не помог, так как не понимает текст месяца соответственно` - а зачем вам "текст месяца"? Делаете свойство, привязываете его (чтоб было как на скрине, прям в привязке пишете `{Binding Date, StringFormat=MMMM}` (ну или что-то типа этого)), делаете две кнопки, привязываете их к командам, в которых пишете `dateTime.AddMonths(1);` и `dateTime.AddMonths(-1);` соответственно, все, у вас всегда нужная дата, без каких либо костылей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы назвал это основой основ привязок.

Ок, давайте по порядку:

1. Делаем класс, который будет источником данных, я назову его `MainViewModel`
2. Делаем класс, который будет реализовывать `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Этих реализаций в интернете полно, я возьму самую стандартную и назову ее `VM`:

   ```
    public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string? propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
    }
   ```
3. Сделаем класс, который реализует нам `ICommand`, опять же, реализаций в интернете полно, я возьму опять же самую простую:

   ```
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
        private readonly Action<object> _execute;

        public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, Action<object> execute)
        {
            _canExecute = canExecute;
            _execute = execute;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
    }
   ```
4. Наследуем `MainViewModel` от `VM`, чтоб мы могли вызывает метод оповещения.
5. Делаем свойство для даты. За дату в C# отвечает `DateTime`. Так, как свойство будет обновляться по мере работы приложения, оно должно вызывать метод оповещения INPC:

   ```
    private DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get => date;
        set => SetField(ref date, value);
    }
   ```
6. Делаем две команды, где первая будет отвечать за вычитание месяца, а другая за добавление. По сути их можно объединить в одну и через параметры передавать значение месяца, но хотел показать "ограничитель", чтоб мы не могли щелкать дальше указанной даты.

   ```
    public ICommand AddMonthCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand SubtractMonthCommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        AddMonthCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => Date.Month != 12, _ => Date = Date.AddMonths(1));
        SubtractMonthCommand = new RelayCommand(_ => Date.Month != 1, _ => Date = Date.AddMonths(-1));
    }
   ```

   Тут поясню (конечно все зависит от реализации класса `RelayCommand`):

   - `_ =>` - это означает "нам не нужно значение, что дает лямбда, обойдемся без него".
   - `_ => Date.Month != 12` - это условие выполнения, если это условие `true`, то кнопка, которая привязалась к этой команде будет активна, если `false`, кнопка станет неактивной.
   - `Date = Date.AddMonths(1)` - то, что будет выполнено при клике по кнопки. Конкретно в этом случае мы к указанной дате добавляем 1 месяц и переписываем ранее существующую дату.
7. Делаем XAML разметку, где все это привязываем. Я не стал сильно заморачиваться, всего лишь 2 кнопки и два `TextBlock` чтоб видет дату.

   ```
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat={}Текущая дата: {0:dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm}}" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Medium"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="&lt;&lt;&lt;" Command="{Binding SubtractMonthCommand}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=MMMM}" TextAlignment="Center" FontSize="14"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="&gt;&gt;&gt;" Command="{Binding AddMonthCommand}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
   ```

   Обратите внимание на `{Binding ...}` - так мы привязываемся к ранее созданному публичному свойству, которое находится в источнике данных. Ну и также обратите внимание на `StringFormat=MMMM`, где задается сразу нужный вид для вывода, без необходимости делать отдельное свойство, конвертор или что либо еще.
8. Осталось задать окну источник данных. Я вам советую прочитать [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553), ну а я лично сделаю в конструкторе окна следующее:

   ```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
   ```

Запускаем, пробуем

[image: Result]

Comment: `AddMonthCommand { get; set; }` можно по идее просто `{ get; }`. И сначала не так прочитал код, а потом увидел, что у вас в конструкторе команды сначала `CanExecute`, а только потом `Execute`, непривычно. [У меня наоборот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1270508/373567), потому что разрешен `null` по умолчанию для `CanExecute`, чтобы не задавать его, когда он не нужен. Отличный ответ.

Comment: @aepot Можно (и даже нужно), да, но это уже пусть будет на совести автора вопроса, я лишь быстро написал `prop`, мне студия сделала свойство, которое я дальше использовал, скажем так, писал на коленке) По поводу команд, ну, реализаций как я и сказал куча, я например в своих проектах часто использую ту,  которую однажды увидел тут на SO и очень сильно полюбил за ее простоту ([тут она мелькает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/220553)), ибо я очень редко использую `CanExecute`. Ну а в вопросе, взял первую попавшуюся из гугла по запросу `icommand implementation`.

Comment: Cпасибо большое!